# Task output caching is enabled, but no build caches are configured or enabled

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-cache

I have configured `buildCache {}` section with remote cache enabled, but the log shows

> Task output caching is enabled, but no build caches are configured or enabled

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add extract(s) from your build file(s), so that we have a chance of seeing what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is logged when the build cache is enabled but [both the local and remote caches are disabled](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/4a41214ca99caea7aab057f4ca2aa9a01b2413a3/subprojects/build-cache/src/main/java/org/gradle/caching/internal/controller/BuildCacheControllerFactory.java#L106).

Have you inadvertently disabled them somehow, e.g. through some `isCiServer` logic that is not working as intended? Can you share your buildCache config?

Adding something like the following to your settings.gradle (with the appropriate url for your cache instance):

```
ext.isCiServer = System.getenv().containsKey("CI")

buildCache {
    local {
        enabled = !isCiServer
    }
    remote(HttpBuildCache) {
        url = 'https://example.com:8123/cache/'
        push = isCiServer
    }
}
```

and either adding

```
org.gradle.caching=true
```

to your `gradle.properties`, or

```
--build-cache
```

to your command line should be enough to get the build cache working.